# Accessing a Map key value in Struts2

Tags: java, forms, struts2

I have a variable map in a database which is being returned and i want to display the details on a web page, the front end is struts2. 
I tried this

```
 <html:iterator value="fields" id="field">
    <html:textfield name="#field.value" key="#field.value" label="#field.key"/> 
</html:iterator>
```

obviously this didn't work, how can i get the Key Name easily so i can have code like this

The idea is to display as follows

```
Name: [  ]
Random: [  ]
Something: [   ]
```

as textfields in a form...

How can i do this simply?

Comment: i am not sure how <html:iterator tag works> not  have seen it in struts2 tag lib

Comment: i just have the struts2 taglib defined as html rather than s

Comment: @TheresaForster You can define the prefix as whatever you want, however I would recommend against it, since (a) not all S2 tags emit HTML, and (b) it's confusing.

Comment: ok!! but i believe that a bit confusing as Dave also pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well not sure how to do it in `<html:iterator>` as never saw it in struts2 tag libor have not came across it.

will use simple `<iteraor>` tag

assuming we have `listmap` as map

```
<s:iterator value="listmap" status="stat">
                    <s:iterator>
                        <tr>
                            <th><s:property value="#stat.index"/></th>
                            <td><s:property value="key"/></td>
                            <td><s:property value="value"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </s:iterator>
                </s:iterator>
```

inner iterator is context sensitive it will use the last value pushed onto the stack. The status attribute gives us a IteratorStatus object each iteration which is useful if we want to know the current iteration.

Comment: ok it works with the property but not the textfield tag which i need it in.    <html:iterator value="fields" >
        <html:iterator>
            <html:property value="key"/>
            <html:textfield name="value" key="value" label="key"/> 
        </html:iterator>
    </html:iterator>

Comment: ok got it working adding ONGL into the field -     <html:iterator value="fields" >
        <html:iterator>
            <html:property value="key"/>
            <html:textfield name="value" key="value" label="%{key}"/> 
        </html:iterator>
    </html:iterator>

Answer (score 2):

You should use map-based form tags if you have arbitrarily-named values to send back to the action. See the [collections](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-AnadvancedexampleforindexedListsandMaps) docs.

```
<s:form ...>
  <s:iterator value="fields" var="field">
    <s:textfield name="sortingKey['%{#field.key}']" label="%{key}" value="%{value}" />
  </s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

Provide a getter/setter for the map in the action.

Also, if you're using Struts 2.1+ the `id` attribute of `<s:iterator>` is deprecated; the loop variable should be named using the `var` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

the prefix "html" is the the taglib of struts2?

if you use the taglib of structs2, let's use prefix s:

you can do it like this

iterate the keys of map, then access the value by key.

```
<s:iterator value="#someMap.keys" var="key">
   <s:textfield value="#someMap[key]" name="someMap[#key]"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: or access the entries. <s:iterator value="#someMap.entries" var="entry">
   <s:textfield value="#entry.value" name="someMap[#entry.key]" label="#entry.key"/>
</s:iterator>

Comment: tried did not work     <html:iterator value="fields.keys" id="field">
            <html:textfield name="#field[key]" key="#field[key]" label="fields[#field]"/> 
    </html:iterator>